# Change values of cells based on the total in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

in excel I'm trying to accomplish a scenario where I have a total in one cell as 100% above which I have three Cells which have their values referenced from other cells please see the image below

[image]

In here my first total cell value is fixed i.e., 50% and on which the next total will be calculated to 100%. 
Now my problem is adjusting the #3 values to 100% based on user input values from before cells

Looking forward for a solution.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You'll have to give us more info, why is there a problem adjusting the #3 values. Right now eveyrthing adds up so it looks like there is no problem.

Comment: I kept those values manually, If im changing by user inputs from **10,10,30** to **20,10,20** the values of my #3 should be adjusted to a total of 100%.  So said the user inputs can be anything but limited to only 50%. Hope this time I'm clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Insert below formulas in B column and check. here formula in cell `A4` is `=SUM(A1:A3)`

[image]

[image]

Comment: So sorry for not conveying properly @maddy I think in my previous comment there is typoerror that user input can be anything but not limited to 50%,so said it can also be less than 50%, i.e., it can be **10,0,0** or **0,10,0 ** . In which case the #3 should show **0,100%,0** like this.

Comment: With respect to  fixed 50% value, you answer works absolutely fine

Comment: formula in cell `A4` is `=SUM(A1:A3)`. so it will work as expected. see my updated answer.